# How do I execute a unix command containing a perl variable in perl

Tags: perl

In the following perl code, I am tring to copy a perl variable $file from one directory to another directory with:

```
"system("cp $file  $Output_Dir);
```

This command writes down the file name alright but then says:

```
cp: cannot stat 'tasmax_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19910101-19951231.nc': No such file or directory
```

The command

```
      system("@sixfiles = ls $Vars[$kk]}*");
```

gives me the error:
    sh: 1: =: not found
I wonder what is wrong with this code. Assistance will be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;

my $debug = 1;

my @Vars = ("pr","tasmin","tasmax");
my $Vars;
my @sixfiles;
my $sixfiles;

my $Input_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Input_Dir";
my $Output_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Output_Dir";

for (my $kk=0; $kk < @Vars; ++$kk) {
    opendir my $in_dir, $Input_Dir or die "opendir failed on $Input_Dir: $! ($^E)";
    while (my $file=readdir $in_dir) {               
        next unless $file =~ /^$Vars[$kk]/;
        next if -d $file;
        print "$file\n";
        print "Copying $file\n" if $debug;
        my $cmd01 = "cp $file  $Output_Dir";
        print "Doing system ($cmd01)\n" if $debug;
        system ($cmd01);
        system("@sixfiles = ls $Vars[$kk]}*");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `@sixfiles`? You do not seem to use the array for anything

Comment: Why not use the core [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy) module instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my @Vars = ("pr","tasmin","tasmax");
my $Input_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Input_Dir";
my $Output_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Output_Dir";

opendir my $in_dir, $Input_Dir or die "opendir failed on $Input_Dir: $! ($^E)";
while (my $file=readdir $in_dir) {
    next if ($file eq '.') || ($file eq '..');
    next if -d $file;
    next if !grep { $file =~ /^$_/ } @Vars;
    say "Copying $file";
    $file = File::Spec->catfile( $Input_Dir, $file );
    system "cp", $file, $Output_Dir;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> system ($cmd01);
> ```
>
> Gives:
>
> ```
> cp: cannot stat '<long-but-correct-file-name>': No such file or directory
> ```

This is almost certainly because you are not running the code from `$Input_Dir`, so that file doesn't exist in your current directory. You need to either `chdir` to the correct directory or add the directory path to the front of the file name variable.

> ```
> system("@sixfiles = ls $Vars[$kk]}*");
> ```

This code makes no sense. The code passed to `system()` needs to be Unix shell code. That's the `ls $Vars[$kk]}*` bit (but I'm not sure where that `}` comes from). You can't populate a Perl array inside a shell command. You would need to capture the value returned from the `ls` command and then parse it somehow to separate it into a list.

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank all of you for spending your  precious time to look at my code. Thanks @Håkon Hægland, the code you provided does not give any error but nothing is copied. I will spend some time on it to see if it can give me results. I use "atsixfiles" later, I just wanted to know how to put it in code. There is an error in that the } at the end should not be there. I got this (wrongly) from what I do in copying files over ftp as "atfiles = ftp->ls". Obviously my use in the current context is wrong. Is there a way of putting it? Overall the responses I got may help me progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

my @Vars = ("pr", "tasmin", "tasmax");
my $Vars;
my $Input_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Input_Dir";
my $Output_Dir = "/home/zmumba/DATA/Output_Dir";
my $cpsrc, $cpdest = '';

print "No Write Permission: $!" unless(-w $Output_Dir);

for my $findex (0 .. $#Vars) {
    $cpsrc = qq($Input_Dir/$Vars[$findex]);

    print "$Vars[$findex]\n";
    print "Copying $Vars[$findex]\n" if $debug;
    my $cmd01 = "cp $cpsrc $Output_Dir";
    print "Doing system ($cmd01)\n" if $debug;
    system($cmd01);
}
```

You don't have to go through each file in source dir. You already know the files to copy from source.

Comment: Thanks @Cheruvattil, I will give you feedback tomorrow after I have access to my computer.